BizTalk 2006 Business Rule Composer, rule sets loading time optimization during Composer startup
Is there any way to decrease time of loading rule set versions in policy explorer? I have lots of versions of policies and loading it takes a lot of time. Maybe there is any possibility to limit the number of rule set versions loaded, for example to a couple of last active versions?
I noticed that Composer always loads up to 100 rule set versions, although there are more than 100 versions in the database. Can I have this limit decreased?

So why not remove the older version of the policies?  It will only use the latest published version

It's rather my last option. I would prefer the data remain intact.

Unfortunately there are no such configuration options for the Business Rules Composer.
What you could do is export the older Polices that are no longer used, and then delete them.
